# error insserv with script

Tags: 14.04, scripts, dns, debian

I try to install Unbound with the following website:

http://www.unix-tutorials.com/go.php?id=3681

I copied the script :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# unbound        This shell script takes care of starting and stopping
#                unbound (DNS server).

exec="/usr/local/sbin/unbound"
prog="unbound"
config="/var/unbound/unbound.conf"
pidfile="/var/run/unbound.pid"
rootdir="/var/unbound"

case "$1" in
    start)
        [ -x $exec ] || exit 5
        [ -f $config ] || exit 6
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "

        # setup root jail
        if [ -s /etc/localtime ]; then
            [ -d ${rootdir}/etc ] || mkdir -p ${rootdir}/etc ;
            if [ ! -e ${rootdir}/etc/localtime ] || /usr/bin/cmp -s /etc/localtime ${rootdir}/etc/localtime; then
                cp -fp /etc/localtime ${rootdir}/etc/localtime
            fi;
        fi;
        if [ -s /etc/resolv.conf ]; then
            [ -d ${rootdir}/etc ] || mkdir -p ${rootdir}/etc ;
            if [ ! -e ${rootdir}/etc/resolv.conf ] || /usr/bin/cmp -s /etc/resolv.conf ${rootdir}/etc/resolv.conf; then
                cp -fp /etc/resolv.conf ${rootdir}/etc/resolv.conf
            fi;
        fi;
        if ! egrep -q '^/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+'${rootdir}'/dev/log' /proc/mounts; then
            [ -d ${rootdir}/dev ] || mkdir -p ${rootdir}/dev ;
            [ -e ${rootdir}/dev/log ] || touch ${rootdir}/dev/log
            mount --bind -n /dev/log ${rootdir}/dev/log >/dev/null 2>&1;
        fi;
        if ! egrep -q '^/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+'${rootdir}'/dev/random' /proc/mounts; then
            [ -d ${rootdir}/dev ] || mkdir -p ${rootdir}/dev ;
            [ -e ${rootdir}/dev/random ] || touch ${rootdir}/dev/random
            mount --bind -n /dev/random ${rootdir}/dev/random >/dev/null 2>&1;
        fi;

        # if not running, start it up here
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $pidfile --exec $exec -- -c $config
        echo
        ;;

    stop)
        echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $pidfile
        echo
        if egrep -q '^/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+'${rootdir}'/dev/log' /proc/mounts; then
            umount ${rootdir}/dev/log >/dev/null 2>&1
        fi;
        if egrep -q '^/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+'${rootdir}'/dev/random' /proc/mounts; then
            umount ${rootdir}/dev/random >/dev/null 2>&1
        fi;
        ;;

    restart)
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $pidfile
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $pidfile --exec $exec -- -c $config
        ;;

    reload)
        start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $pidfile --exec $exec
        ;;

    force_reload)
        start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $pidfile --exec $exec
        ;;

    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}"
        exit 2
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

But I received an error when i want to update-rc.d, with the command:

```
update-rc.d unbound defaults
```

The error is:

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: script 'unbound' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service postfix and unbound if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service unbound at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service postfix at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service sendsigs at depth 4
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

Hope you can help me to fix theses errors.

Many thanks.